# trying to work dynamically with object properties in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to sort out if this is plausible but have gotten syntax errors at best. So I am wondering if it is at all possible.

What I have is an object (example only)

```
var myObj = {
       something1_max:50,
       something1_enabled:false,
       something1_locked:true,
       something2_max:100,
       something2_enabled:false,
       something2_locked:true,
       something3_max:10,
       something3_enabled:true,
       something3_locked:true
    }
```

and what I want to do through a function is do something like again for example to sum things up..

```
function displayDetails(theScope, obj)
{
   console.log(obj.[theScope]_max);
}

(function(){displayDetails('something3', myObj);})()
```

so when `displayDetails()` is called whatever the scope I can see in this example the max for that scope. In the console log for the example I would hope to see `10`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic object property name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamic-object-property-name)

Comment: All though this is in part a duplicate question, the solution is different. If you read the whole question here, you'll note that the I am trying to work with both the prefix and suffix of the object properties differently where only a part of the overall property name is the dynamic portion sought after, leaving the suffix static in the equation. Where the "duplicate" solution linked to only mentions on the whole property name as a dynamic entity. So I agree in the similarity, but its a different concept in it of itself, that others may seek out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properties of JavaScript objects can always be accessed as a string using the *bracket* syntax, ie `object['property']`.  This, of course, means you can build that string dynamically:

```
console.log(obj[theScope + '_max']);
```

Comment: Well, you can tell your running on fumes, and coffee vapors when simplicity like that evades ya.. oh man..

Answer (score 1):

Put the property name string in brackets.

```
console.log(obj[theScope + '_max']);
```